# Using MVC scaffolding repository with inherited classes (table-per-type) isn't working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, inheritance, repository-pattern

I have a class `Tenant` that inherits from `UserProfile`. I'm using table-per-type inheritance so my context class looks like this:

```
// 1 DbSet for superclass UserProfile
public DbSet<LetLord.Models.UserProfile> UserProfile { get; set; }
```

I'm using repository classes for my data access and I created `TenantRepository` with the following package manager command:

> Scaffold Controller Tenant -Repository

When I try to run my application, all references to Tenant in the TenantRepository throw the following error...

> 'MyNamespace.MyContext' does not contain a definition 'Tenant' and no extension for 'Tenant' accepting a first argument 'MyNamespace.MyContext' could be found.

...such as the following reference:

```
public IQueryable<Tenant> All
{
    get { return context.Tenant; } // error line here
}
```

When using table-per-type inheritance only a `DbSet` for base classes should be included, so I understand why I'm getting the error.

How is using repositories with derived classes implemented in scenarios such as mine?

---

**EDIT**

How is above accomplished when using `.Add()`, `.Find()`, `.Remove()` etc?

Same error as described above for the previously mentioned methods:

```
public Tenant Find(int id)
{
    return context.UserProfile.OfType<Tenant>().Find(id); // error at .Find()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public IQueryable<Tenant> All
{
    get { return context.UserProfile.OfType<Tenant>(); }
}
```

This will only return Tenants.

For other methods like Add, Find, Remove:

```
public Tenant Find(int id)
{
    // a few different options here -- assumes your key property is Id
    return context.UserProfile.OfType<Tenant>().SingleOrDefault(t => t.Id == id);

    // option 2 
    // even though your context does not expose a DbSet<Tenant>, you can still
    // use the Set<TResult>() method to get only tenants this way
    return context.Set<Tenant>().Find(id);
}

public void Add(Tenant tenant)
{
    context.Add(tenant);
}

public void Remove(Tenant tenant)
{
    context.Set<Tenant>().Remove(tenant);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works, but please see edit RE other repository methods.

Comment: I don't know what those methods look like but I will give it a shot.

Comment: They're part of the repository class that's auto-created when I run the package manager command described in the question.

Comment: @MattSull87 Try these options. Even if you don't expose DbSet<Tenant> the context can still get a DbSet<Tenant> by using the Set<> generic method. You can always just fall back to using that if needed.